# VBScript FTP Login with Username and Password

Tags: vbscript, ftp, authentication, passwords

I am trying to update a VBScript (very little experience with this, I do a lot of VB.NET), that reads an FTP directory and moves certain files to a new local directory on a daily basis. I have old code that works on an FTP site that uses anonymous logins, but I now need it to access an FTP site that requires username and password.

Here is my current code -

```
Sub MoveNSPurolatorFile()

Dim NSPurolatorFTPSite, NSPurolatorMoveFilePath, NSPurolatorFTPFolder, NSPurolatorFTPFileName

Dim folder, files
Dim fso

set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

NSPurolatorFTPSite="\\xxx.xxx.x.xx\"
NSPurolatorMoveFilePath = "F:\TestDirectory"
NSPurolatorFTPFolder = "TestFolder"

NSPurolatorFTPFileName =  "MAN0201.CSV"

If InStr(NSPurolatorFTPFileName, "_processed") = 0 and InStr(NSPurolatorFTPFileName, ".CSV") > 0 Then

    If fso.FolderExists(NSPurolatorFTPSite & NSPurolatorFTPFolder) Then

        If fso.FileExists(NSPurolatorFTPSite & NSPurolatorFTPFolder & NSPurolatorFTPFileName) Then

            objfile.writeline "NS Purolator File Found: " & NSPurolatorFTPSite & NSPurolatorFTPFolder & NSPurolatorFTPFileName
            fso.copyFile NSPurolatorFTPSite & NSPurolatorFTPFolder & NSPurolatorFTPFileName, NSPurolatorMoveFilePath & "\"  

        Else
            objfile.writeline "File does not exist: " & NSPurolatorFTPSite & NSPurolatorFTPFolder & NSPurolatorFTPFileName 
        End If 

    End If

End If

Next

End Sub
```

It says the folder does not exist, but I know it does and when I run this code against an ftp site that does not require username and password it works fine. I guess my question is - How do I pass in the username and password using VBScript to the ftp site before trying to access folders, etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This really is an incredibly bad way to do this.  You can't just treat folders on a remote FTP site as local folders.

You really should be using InetCtrls.Inet.1

Here's an example I lifted from somewhere else that does not do what you want, but contains all the parts you need - you need to pick it apart to suit your needs.

```
'Option Explicit
'const progname="FTP upload script by Richard Finegold"
'const url = "ftp://ftp.myftpsite.com"
'const rdir = "mydir"
'const user = "anonymous"
'const pass = "myname@mymailsite.com"

'This is an example of ftp'ing without calling the external "FTP" command
'It uses InetCtrls.Inet.1 instead
'Included is a "hint" for simple downloading

'Sources:
'http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/partbook/ipwvb5/loggingontoftpserver.htm
'http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/partbook/egvb6/addinginternettransfercontrol.htm
'http://cwashington.netreach.net/ - search on "ftp" - inspiration only!

'Insist on arguments
dim objArgs
Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments
If 0=objArgs.Count Then
   MsgBox "No files selected for operation!", vbOkOnly + vbCritical, progname
   WScript.Quit
End If


'Force console mode - csforce.vbs (with some reorganization for efficiency)
dim i
if right(ucase(wscript.FullName),11)="WSCRIPT.EXE" then
  dim args, y
  For i = 0 to objArgs.Count - 1
    args = args + " " + objArgs(i)
  Next
  Set y = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  y.Run "cscript.exe " & wscript.ScriptFullName + " " + args, 1
  wscript.quit
end if


'Do actual work
dim fso, ftpo
set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set ftpo = WScript.CreateObject("InetCtls.Inet.1")     'Msinet.ocx
ftpo.URL = url
ftpo.UserName = user
ftpo.Password = pass
WScript.Echo "Connecting..."
ftpo.Execute , "CD " & rdir
do
'     WScript.Echo "."
     WScript.Sleep 100     'This can take a while loop while ftpo.StillExecuting


for i = 0 to objArgs.Count - 1
     dim sLFile
     sLFile = objArgs(i)

     if (fso.FileExists(sLFile)) then
          WScript.Echo "Uploading " & sLFile & " as " & FSO.GetFileName(sLFile) & " "
          ftpo.Execute , "Put " & sLFile & " " & FSO.GetFileName(sLFile)
          'ftpo.Execute , "Get " & sRemoteFile & " C:\" & sLFile
          do
          'WScript.Echo "."
               WScript.Sleep 100     'This can take a while
          loop while ftpo.StillExecuting
     else
          MsgBox Chr(34) & sLFile & Chr(34) & " does not exist!", _
           vbOkOnly, progname
     end if
next
WScript.Echo "Closing"
ftpo.Execute , "Close"
WScript.Echo "Done!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty nice way to do it - I'm sure this could be improved upon, but I just got it going.. :-)

```
Dim fso, folder1, folder2, folder2a
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set folder2a = fso.GetFolder("C:\temp")

ftpFolderString = "ftp://username:password@ftp.ftpsite.com/folderpath" 

targetFoldder = "C:\temp"
fileSearchStr = "searchstring"

Dim SH, txtFolderToOpen, thing
Set SH = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 

'SH.Open txtFolderToOpen 
Set folder1 = SH.NameSpace(ftpFolderString)
Set folder2 = SH.NameSpace(targetFoldder)
For Each item In folder1.items

    If InStr(LCase(item.Name),fileSearchStr) > 0 Then
        Debug.WriteLine item.Name
        folder2.CopyHere item,4
        WScript.Sleep(200)
        For Each item2 In folder2a.Files
            If item2.Name = item.Name Then
                While item2.Size < item.Size 
                    WScript.Sleep(200)
                Wend
            End If
        Next
        WScript.Sleep(200)
    End If

Next
Set SH = Nothing 
Debug.WriteLine "Done"
```

Answer (score -1):

How is the script being run? Manually, automatically? By a service?

Mapped-letter drives are not always available when running as a service.

Experiment with the script to ensure that it even able to see the F:\ drive, and then see what else is visible.

Comment: It will be run automatically, but it is not the F:\drive giving me the problem. It is the FTP site before that. The code doesn't even make it to the F:\drive part.

Comment: Since the error was "folder doesn't exist" I assumed that you were referring to the local file-system. It's not completely clear.

Answer (score -1):

Is the FTP site accessed by a UNC path (looks like it is)?  If it is just a standard FTP address then you can incorporate the username / password in the URL e.g. ftp://user:pass@myftpsite.com.  If it is a UNC path that you are trying to access using different credentials then the easiest way would probably be to map a drive, do the work and then unmap the drive.  2 different approaches can be found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/browse_thread/thread/be15a6c7c3e97e42)