# Need to download a txt file with a varying (based on date) name from ftp into excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos

The ftp requires no credentials.

I've never worked with VBA before, but I'm assuming it can be done. Anyone have any guidance with either code examples or websites with VBA guidance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063533/vbscript-ftp-login-with-username-and-password

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this code to get you started using **WinHHTPRequest**:

[Mr Excel: Download file using Excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/353006-download-file-excel.html#post1744744)

Comment: Thank you, but I should have noted I'm doing this on a mac. WinHHTP doesn't work it seems.